# Datagrid selected item

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I was wondering how can you pass the selected datagrid item to the eventhandler?

My datagrid:

```
<div>
    <kendo-grid [data]="gridData"
    [sortable]="true"
    [selectable]="true"
    (selectionChange)="selectRow($event)"
    >
```

My grid.component.ts

```
private selectRow(event:any){
        console.log(event)
    }
```

How do I pass the selected row into the event handler?

**Update**

I have solved it now like this:

```
private selectRow(event:any){
        console.log(event)
        let i = event.index
        let selectedRow = this.gridData[i];
        console.log(selectedRow)
    }
```

Can somebody tell me if this is the correct way?
Or is there a better way to solve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are using the recommended way for finding a data item from select event. We do not provide the dataItem as part of the event argument, as it is easily accessible from the handler anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Now we can get the dataItem directly from the event ,

```
 (selectionChange)="selectRow($event)"
```

And then in the component we can get all rows selected from `selectionEvent`

```
 onSelect(e: SelectionEvent) {
        if (e.selectedRows.length > 0) {
            var rows = e.selectedRows;
            console.log(rows[0].dataItem);
        }
 }
```